# Loss is decreasing but val_loss not!

Tags: lstm, loss-function

If loss is decreasing but val_loss not, what is the problem and how can I fix it?

I get such vague result:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this isn't backwards? It would be odd for validation loss to be consistently lower than train. Not impossible, but atypical.

Answer (score 4):

This indicates that model is not generalizing (it is over-fitting). Few options are :

1. Get more training data
2. Reduce complexity of model (Number of LSTM layers, complexity of dense layers)

Andrew NG has a good video on this topic :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSd30QGMl88

A tutorial specific to LSTM :

https://machinelearningmastery.com/diagnose-overfitting-underfitting-lstm-models/